# How can I install the Google Toolbar for the latest version of Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, google-toolbar

Is there any way to install the Google toolbar for the latest version of Firefox (12.0+)? Recently I have reinstalled Firefox and can't seem to be able to install the Google Toolbar anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I would recommend you don't. What specific part of the toolbar do you need? Firefox already has a built-in search box, you can even mimic Google Chrome's address bar searching with addons like [Instantfox](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/). There's plenty of translation addons, etc., etc.. Everything Google Toolbar could do, there's an addon that does the same. Using unsupported software is often a bad idea.

---

If you still want to go through with it... Firefox 10 addon compatibility checking has been disabled for addons for Firefox 4+. In other words, you can install any addon targeted towards Firefox 4+. Unfortunately, Google Toolbar targets Firefox 3.6.

Luckily, there's an addon that specifically disables compatibility checking for *all* addons. Note many Firefox 3.6 addons are often incompatible with 4+, so YMMV. It is available [here](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/).

Your next step would be to find a source for the actual Toolbar addon. Google has discontinued it and is no longer providing it. A quick search turns up [a potential resource](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Browser-Tweak/Google-Toolbar-for-Firefox.shtml). This is not recommended, but if you really want or need to, just download the (.xpi) addon and run it.

Answer (score 0):

[**Google Toolbar for Firefox Has Been Discontinued.**](http://support.google.com/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&topic=15356&answer=1342452)

Comment: It would be nice to know what the link says without having to visit the link itself.  Google has a nasty habit of getting rid of support articles.